# Running a compiled Haskell program:

Tags: haskell

```
data Figura = Circulo Float | Rectangulo Float Float


esRedondo :: Figura -> Bool
esRedondo (Circulo _) = True
esRedondo (Rectangulo _ _) = False 

area :: Figura -> Float
area (Circulo r) = pi*r*r
area (Rectangulo h b) = h*b
```

I get an error :
`The function`main' is not defined in module `Main'

Answer (score 5):

If you want to create a runnable executable, you need to define `main :: IO ()`, which will be executed when the program is run.

Comment: I am beginner in Haskell, as I implemented it?

Comment: @user3754485 (Assuming you meant "how do I implement `main`?") That depends on what you want to happen when your program is run. A simple example would be `main = print (area (Circulo 42))`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what you probably want to do if you are using ghc. Do `ghci yourprogram.hs`. This will allow to interact with your program interactively. Your program doesn't currently do anything by itself, so this will be more useful.

Answer (score 0):

There are two reasons why this happens:

- you haven't specified a module name in your file and when you don't specify the module then GHC assumes that you are in the `Main` module.
- you haven't specified the entry point of a Haskell program, that is the [main function](http://www.haskell.org/tutorial/io.html).

The sum of this two reasons gives your error: no `main` function in the `Main` module.

One solution could be to add the `main` function:

```
main :: IO ()
main = return () -- do nothing
```

or, in alternative, compile your file as a library and then load it in `ghci` (or just load the `.hs` file in `ghci`). In this case you should give a module name to your library:

```
module Geometry where
[...]
```

and then import it where you use it with `import Geometry`.